# Exclude ViewGroup from transition except one specific child

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to exclude a view group let's say recycler view from shared element return transition. But the thing is i don't want all children of recycler view to exclude i want specific recycler view child to include the transition.

```
Slide transition = new Slide(Gravity.END); 
transition.excludeTarget(recyclerView, true); 
transition.addTarget(ImageView.class); 
setExitTransition(transition); 
setReturnTransition(transition);
```

I don't understand why is above code not working. Please let me know if you have any ideas or any way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you get with this code?

Comment: it just exclude whole recyclerview. There's an imageview in one of my recyclerview items. It doesn't respect this `transition.addTarget(ImageView.class);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What's the problem?**

The problem comes from [`Transition#captureValues()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/transition/Transition.java#1421) function `if` statements:

```
    void captureValues(ViewGroup sceneRoot, boolean start) {
        clearValues(start);
        if ((mTargetIds.size() > 0 || mTargets.size() > 0)
                && (mTargetNames == null || mTargetNames.isEmpty())
                && (mTargetTypes == null || mTargetTypes.isEmpty())) {
            ...
        } else {
            captureHierarchy(sceneRoot, start);
        }
        ...
    }
```

The first statement doesn't pass, thus the `else` case is executed, which makes your `addTarget(ImageView.class)` to be disregarded.

**Why doesn't the first statement pass?**

Because `addTarget(Class)` [will change](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/transition/Transition.java#1035) `mTargetTypes` field, thus both `mTargetIds` and `mTargets` would be left empty.

Instead, perform `addTarget(int)`, which [will change](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/transition/Transition.java#979) `mTargetIds`.

Thus, here's what your transition will look like:

```
    Slide transition = new Slide(Gravity.END); 
    transition.addTarget(R.id.some_imageview); 
    setExitTransition(transition); 
    setReturnTransition(transition);
```

No need to perform `transition.excludeTarget()`, because as stated in [`addTarget()` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/transition/Transition.html#addTarget(int)):

> Setting targetIds constrains the Transition to only listen for, and act on, views with these IDs. Views with different IDs, or no IDs whatsoever, will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. If view group has a background this still adds the background to the transition. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Can you post a gif with that behavior?

Comment: I'm sorry i just realized it's working as expected. But my actual problem remains. I'm trying to implement pull back animation on recyclerview. I have viewPager as a recycler view item. And viewPager contains an imageview. I'm trying to make a slide transition if viewPager position is bigger than 0. But it's somehow doesn't make the slide transition. You can see it from the [gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/tV1PsEnENNR3G/giphy.gif). I'll really appreciate if you can help or give me ideas about this. Otherwise I'm just gonna accept your answer as it is.

Comment: I wonder why are you performing `addTarget(Class)`? `addTarget(Class)` will make the transition to be applied to all the view which are assigned from that class, i.e. all subclasses of `ImageView` would participate in the transition. But as I understand you only need to perform transition for only one view, that is you have to apply `addTarget(View)` overload.

Comment: I'm using addTarget(View) right now. It was just an example for the brief explanation.